# End a multiplayer game on finishMatch

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing a turn based multiplayer game in `Android` using `Google Play Game Services`.

I have successfully ended the game when the user clicks the Finish `Button`:

```
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(mGoogleApiClient, mMatch.getMatchId(), mMatch.getData(), creatorResult, opponentResult)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                    processResult(result);
                }
            });
```

The current player's game gets updated in the "Completed Games" section.

However the opponent's game is listed as "My Turn"

From the `Developing a Turn Based Multiplayer Game in Android` page:

"Play Game services sends a notification to all other match participants to inform them that the match is over. These participants see this match under Your Turn category in their respective match list UIs. *At this point, your game can call finishMatch() for these participants to save their final game data.* Invoking this method also moves the match to the Completed Matches category in the participant’s match list UI."

How do I call `finishMatch` for the other players?

--Is it through the `mGoogleApiClient`

--Or is there a way to make the oppononent's match status = `MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETE`

Can someone please help?

Comment: Anybody have advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the following call on each of the other players devices:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch( mGoogleApiClient, mMatch.getMatchId());
```

This will cause the following status changes on each players device:

- Match status will change from MATCH_STATUS_ACTIVE to
  MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETE
- Match turn Status will change from
  MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN to MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE.
- The participant status of the player will change from STATUS_JOINED to
  STATUS_FINISHED.

Note that a players participant status may remain STATUS_JOINED on the other players devices (at least thats what I see in my implementation).